# How do I maintain the state of a show/hide button and content after executing a search using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

In my Ruby on Rails application, I have an index page with Ransack filtering. The Ransack form can be shown or hidden with an onclick event. My current code works fine, but once a search is executed in the form, the button goes back to "Show filters" although the form is already visible. How can I fix this to maintain its state after a search and retain functionality?

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div>
  <p id="filterToggle" style="cursor: pointer;">Show filter</p>
    <div id="filterForm" class="mb-2">
    <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name_i_cont, "Filter by name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name_i_cont, :placeholder => "Enter a few characters" %>
     <div>
       <%= link_to "Clear filters", digs_path(@dig) %>
       <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-outline-secondary mt-2" %>
     </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript function:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const filterToggle = document.getElementById('filterToggle')
        const filterForm = document.getElementById('filterForm');

        filterForm.style.display = 'none';

        filterToggle.onclick = function() {
          if (filterForm.style.display !== 'none') {
            filterForm.style.display = 'none';
            filterToggle.innerText = 'Show filter';
          }
          else {
            filterForm.style.display = 'block';
            filterToggle.innerText = 'Hide filter';
          }
        }
      });
```

Thanks!